# C# HttpServer Requests / Sending + Recieving

Tags: c#, http

For understanding i experiement at the moment with Webservers in C#. 
 I know how to handle requests like this (part of all code)

```
 p.outputStream.WriteLine("<html><body><h1>test server</h1>");
```

Which will return when there is a incoming Request as example when Browser reload the Site.

My Question is now: 
How can i send Post Headers or something to the Browser? Like the Webserver is sending the actually Time every Secound to the Browser and the Browser is showing it in realtime? I was hearing something about sending Https to a Website oO ?
At least what i want is displaying the Time in realtime or changing a text in realtime and the Browser is showing the change of a Text in realtime.

Is this possible at least or is it a wrong way? 
I prefer to dont use any Plugins, Classes or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fundamental to the HTTP protocol that the server only responds to requests from the client. The server can't initiate any contact with the client.

Things like a continuously updating clock in the browser are implemented with Javascript in the browser, where the Javascript either updates the page or triggers further requests to the server.  There's a specific technique, Ajax, for javascript to send requests to the server outside of the normal GET or POST of the whole page that browser's originally supported.

There are newer techniques, some based on polling, some based on HTML5 browser features (web sockets), that allow asynchronous two-way communication between the client and the server.  The SignalR libraries wraps these in a nice, high-level abstraction.

(And if you're going to do any serious software development, you better get used to using Plugins, Classes, libraries, frameworks, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your Answer :) Yeah i develope Now for 7 years mostly in Area Web... With PHP, Java, Ajax ,... i know all these Methods. But me/we need or want a other way than Client Site Ajax Script :) 
Do you have any other Way of Comunication? Cause i cant talk about what i want to do here official. 
But